# Session variables not retained on postback in some cases

Tags: asp.net, session

In one of my ASP website I am facing problem with session variable.

Following is extract of my code.

```
    If Page.IsPostBack = False And newFrmReply = False Then

        Dim mystream As IO.Stream

        mystream = Request.InputStream()
        Dim filebytes(mystream.Length) As Byte
        mystream.Read(filebytes, 0, mystream.Length)
        For i = 0 To UBound(filebytes)
            If filebytes(i) <> 0 Then
                reg.poststr = reg.poststr & Chr(filebytes(i))
            End If

        Next
        Session("poststring") = reg.poststr 
    Else
        reg.poststr = Session("poststring") 
    End If

    serial = reg.getvalueFromUrl("Serial", reg.poststr)


    If serial > 0 Then
            TxtSl_no.Text = Mid(serial, 1, 5)
    Else
            TxtSl_no.Visible = True
            lblSerialNo.Visible = True
    End If
```

Initially Session("poststring") is set from string posted to URL. We have given one ASP button. On button click postback happens.
After postback wherever session is read, it returns empty string. 
String posted to URL is not empty as TxtSl_no.Text is having non empty value (which is based on posted string). 
In web.config I have set session time out to 24 hr. `<sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>`.
In 99% of client PCs this code is working fine. Only in few PCs blank strings are getting saved to database.

On postback txtsl_no.text viewstate is retained. Hence on postback txtsl_no.text is retained.

Comment: may be it is getting null value in `reg.poststr`?

Comment: String posted to URL is not empty as TxtSl_no.Text is having non empty value (which is based on posted string)

Comment: Today we checked in same PC again. But its not giving err. Working fine. Day before yesterday we tried some 3 to 4 times, every time with err.